# Unable to call an API on drop down change for Angular Data Table and Refresh the current data

Tags: angular, angular-datatables

I am using An Angular Datatable, what I want, after the dropdown change I have to call an API and get the recent data and append it to the current data table. I have tried to destroy() method but it's not working on the first drop-down change after that it working fine but not passing the recently selected date to API instead of it passes the second last selected value to API input

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this with the help of watcher. Lets assume that you defined ng-model for you dropdown as "selectedValue" and dataTable is Array with which table data is populated.

```
$scope.$watch('selectedValue', function(newValue, oldValue){
  if (newValue !== oldValue){
   //Make API call based on selected value and append it to array.
   dataTable.append(result);
  }
});
```

After every dropdown change, above watcher will gets called.

Comment: The problem is -> There is a dropdown which contains the values like Apple, PineApple, Grapes so if I first click on Apple the API get called but the value is undefined after that I click on Grapes the API gets called with the value of "Apple" that is the main problem. Should I share my code? N currently using Angular version 4

Comment: Use newValue as parameter while calling API instead of oldValue. You can use different watcher syntax also.                 $scope.$watch('selectedValue', function(value){
          if(value){
             //Make API call based on selected value and append it to array.
   dataTable.append(result);
          }
        });

Comment: Need more explanation